# Removing ice blockage between freezer and fridge in GE Monogram side-by-side

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, ducts, ice, freezer

I have a GE Monogram Fridge/Freezer Model # ZIS42NYB, Serial # SV036084.  It's about 25 years old and I'll probably replace it as money/time permits.
HOWEVER, I'd like to have it limp along a little longer. Every 6 months to a year, the fridge gets too warm (52 F instead of ~40F). The freezer is perfect.  I'm pretty sure I know the immediate reason for this. My family has the annoying habit of leaving the fridge door open for extended periods, or shoving something large in fridge, slamming the door, and leaving the room before they can notice the door has popped open.
To be clear, replacing the family is not an option. I'm very much attached to them :).
I can remove the light fixture at the back of the freezer and see the ice build up.  I have tried to scrape the ice away.  It has not helped. I suspect, there is still considerable ice in the duct (not much scraped away) and that it is more on the fridge side.
**Is there a way to get at this duct from the fridge side?**
**Are there other areas I should look at?** Preferably that are accessible from the front of fridge (it's a built in and BIG)
I have strong confidence that another method will fix the problem (for 6 months to a year), and that is too unplug the whole unit for 48 hours.  I might well do that, but as you can appreciate, it's a hassle. Hence the reason I'm looking for other solutions.  If the answer really is, "unplug it".  How long do I really need to unplug for?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: You need to unplug until it defrosts.  If you live in an area where it gets below freezing, borrow a few coolers and stash the contents of your fridge in them outdoors, while you let the fridge defrost.

Comment: I'm in an area (coastal southern california) where the outside temp maybe gets as low as 54F.  Usually, that's a great thing, but not if you want to defrost fridge/freezer. :)

Comment: A hair dryer might speed things up a bit. If the freezer is frost-free, ensure the heating element is working or the ice will build right back up again.

Comment: Sounds like naysaying. You don't need 48 hours to defrost a fridge, that's just defeatist talk.  To solve the "leaving the door open" problem, you need a "door left open" whistle.  If you're enough of a tech-head to put temperature data loggers in the fridge, you can figure that out.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica How long do you think you need to defrost fridge/freezer? I'm thinking of ice in the duct between fridge and freezer. As I said, I think I scraped out some ice from the freezer side, but I suspect there is more. Hence the desire to get at it from fridge side.  As for training the family, I suspect nothing will work there. There are after market door open alerts, but I suspect folks would simply ignore them! I will say the fridge is old. That is why I'm amenable to getting a new one.

Comment: You'll need a door alert on the new fridge too @Dave.  I would say 2-4 hours. Put things in coolers is what I do. Make sure the family knows what a PITA this is.

Comment: Make the *family* put the things in the coolers!

Comment: What? no one remembers how to defrost a fridge anymore? Put an old towel in the bottom and put a pot or two of boiling water in the fridge - replace when cooled down. Will be done in no time. BTW ice usually means the defroster element is broken...